# Bootstrap col-push, col-pull

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-8">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason for the push and pull is that I want those 2 columns to swap on mobile.  Currently it works fine on mobile, however on desktop - instead of looking like this:

[image]

The columns jump out of the col-md-9 like so:

[image]

If I remove the push and pull, they stay put.  So it's definitely something to do with that.

How do I stop them breaching the col-md-9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `push/pull` classes.

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it would be something simple - thanks.  I'll accept when the counter runs down.